# Position an element x% of a way along with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to position an element so that of the available space, 1/3 is above it and 2/3 are below. This is a React Native project so I can use flexbox but not grid or floats.

This code works but it's not very clean having to have empty elements `div.first` and `div.last`, can it be done without them?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background: gold
}

.first {
  flex: 1;
}

.last {
  flex: 2
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="last"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/adsfdsfhdsafkhdsafjkdhafskjds/pen/PoPjdad

Comment: Pseudo elements on a flex container are considered flex items. [revised codepen](https://codepen.io/Figueroa5566/pen/gOaRdEB?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

How about using margin like this?

Edit: Just add `overflow-y:hidden;` to body

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.one {
  background: gold;
    margin:33vh 0 66vh 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">One</div>
```

Comment: This increases the height of the page so that there are always scrollbars.